# How to block users from creating flows on a SharePoint site

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-flow

I have a particular SharePoint site which I want to restrict users from accessing via Microsoft flow or PowerApps.
I only want the SharePoint designer workflows or Microsoft Flow created by the site admin to be the only functional workflows on the site.

The regular users have contribute permissions on the site. They are already successfully restricted from creating SharePoint designer workflows but I don't know how to restrict them from creating Microsoft flow.

Kindly assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flow runs outside of SharePoint and most likely calls web services, so the only restrictions are normal SharePoint permissions on the user to read or update items. Another way to think about it... any user with read permissions can read data from a SharePoint list using a web browser or the REST API (web services). The SharePoint web services are callable from JavaScript, PowerShell, Flow, PowerApps, Power BI and just about any programming tool set. The same applies to update and delete.

As an example, open a web browser, visit one of your SharePoint sites, and edit your URL for something like this:

```
https://yourDomain/sites/yourSite/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('yourListName')/items
```

Comment: To add to this, disabling Flow is an all-or-nothing affair. There is no selective way to disable it, other than deny a user to access the content and/or remove their Flow license.

Answer (score 0):

There is a hidden workflow group and by default all the groups are added here mirroring site permissions. Just make sure you remove all of the groups or edit permissions level to read only.